How to OKTA in Laravel using Laravel Socialite package
If you have solution please suggest me How to OKTA in Laravel using Laravel Socialite package
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
{
    $response = (object) Socialite::driver('okta')->getClientAccessTokenResponse();
    $user = Socialite::driver('okta')->user();
    $localUser = User::where('email', $user->email)->first();
    // create a local user with the email and token from Okta
    if (! $localUser) {
        $localUser = User::create([
            'email' => $user->email,
            'name'  => $user->name,
            'token' => $user->token,
        ]);
    } else {
        // if the user already exists, just update the token:
        $localUser->token = $user->token;
        $localUser->save();
    }
    try {
        Auth::login($localUser);
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
        return redirect('/login-okta');
    }
    return redirect('/dashboard');
}

I don't know what it mean and did not found anything yet about this error. The real problem is it seems to be a random exception (don't understood why it happens). So what this error means and how to avoid it?

What is the error?

Please share the error message along with your code sample, thanks!
